# setting environment variable to numeric value leads to error in python

Tags: python-3.6

Trying to setup ENV variables in the following code

```
import os
dicta = {}

def setv(evar, evalue):
    os.environ[evar] = evalue
    dicta.setdefault('UENV', {}).update({evar: evalue})

# Set environment variables
setv('API_USER', 'username')
setv('API_PASSWORD', 'secret')
setv('NUMBER', 1)
```

on the last statement where NUMBER variable is set to numeric value 1. getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pyenv.py", line 19, in <module>
    setv('NUMBER', 1)
  File "./pyenv.py", line 13, in setv
    os.environ[evar] = evalue
  File "/home/python/3.6.3/1/el-6-x86_64/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 674, in __setitem__
    value = self.encodevalue(value)
  File "/home/python/3.6.3/1/el-6-x86_64/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 744, in encode
    raise TypeError("str expected, not %s" % type(value).__name__)
TypeError: str expected, not int
```

I don't want to convert the variable value to str and keep the value in int. Any thought on keeping NUMBER value as numeric 1 and do not see this error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environment Variables are string values. Typecasting them back into integers after you import them from your environment them is the way to go.